# get wrong list use map function when geting the coresponding elements of a list from another list in python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [True,False,True,False]
```

and I want get the elements of `a` that coresponding to the `True` in `b`, don't use `for` loop.
I use the `map` function to solve it, but it went wrong:

```
def f(x,y):
    if x:
        return y
s = list(map(f,b,a))
```

`s` is `[1, None, 3, None]`， and i don't want the `None`, how can I do?

Comment: List comprehension is the most optimal in this case: `[x for i, x in enumerate(a) if b[i]]` or `[x for x, y in zip(a, b) if y]`. I don't see the reason to insist on not using loops.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `compress`:

```
from itertools import compress
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [True,False,True,False]
s = list(compress(a, b))
```

Output:

```
[1, 3]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `filter` to remove `None`.

**Ex:**

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [True,False,True,False]

def f(x,y):
    if x:
        return y
s = list(filter(None, map(f,b,a)))
print(s)
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 3]
```

Comment: and any other methods?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just [zipping](https://kite.com/python/docs/builtins.zip) 2 lists and choose values corresponding to True?

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [True,False,True,False]

print([x for x, y in zip(a, b) if y])
```